# Classification properties of fusion rings

Tags: rt.representation-theory, fusion-categories

Fusion rings have so many classification properties (I checked the literature a bit) that my head hurts. For practical reasons I define the following three new properties (which might coincide with well-known).
Generic fusion ring: unital, associative, commutative. Without loss of fun assume it's over C and self-dual (I think this restricts only the number of examples, but not their existence, otherwise omit self-dual).
Call a fusion ring "Verlinde" if its S-matrix is symmetric.
Call a function of 6 variables "generalized 6j symbol" if it fulfils the most basic properties of a standard 6j symbol (tetrahedron symmetry, one variable is trivial irrep $\rightarrow$ 6j reduces to Kronecker delta, orthogonality, Biedenharn-Elliott rule). If it also fulfils
some (suitably modified for twists) Racah backcoupling rule, call it "generalized ribbon 6j symbol". (You need a crossing somewhere to derive Racah.)
Call a fusion ring "Elliott" if it has Reshitikhine-Turaev-style invariants via generalized 6j symbols.
Call a fusion ring "Racah"... (the same, only with ribbon 6j).

My guess (based on my faithful Clebsch-O-Matic, which unfortunately can't deal with non-self-dual irreps or outer multiplicities yet) is that fusion rings have the following inclusion rules:
Modular data$\equiv$Racah$\subset$modular$\subset$ribbon$\equiv$Verlinde$\subset$generic fusion ring$\equiv$Elliott.

My question is obviously: What's the correct inclusion sequence? (Feel free to add bynames I forgot :-) And please give a smallest rank example for each type (e.g. for modular data the Fibonacci category $A\bigotimes{A}=1\bigoplus{A}: t=(-1)^{1/5}, dim=t+1/t, 6j[AAA|AAA]=2-dim, twist=t^3$ ).

Comment: What are "Reshethikin-Turaev-style invariants? The Reshethikin-Turaev invariant needs a modular ($\implies$ ribbon) category to work. Why should a "generic fusion ring" be enough for that? In general, why don't you rather think about the different sorts of categories than their fusion rings? There it's very easy and well known: Modular category < ribbon category < spherical fusion category <? fusion category.

Comment: @Turion: Thus "style" - I don't know enough on the field.

Comment: (contd) Assume you do their construction, but no crossings are allowed in the cubic graph. I think you still can get an invariant, with "Elliott" 6j symbols. If someone could tell me the smallest self-dual, no multiplicity fusion ring that is NOT ribbon, I could try my Clebsch-O-Matic on it and settle the matter. (A try with A*A=1,A*B=B,B*B=1+A+2B suggests you are right but don't know whether I programmed multiplicity correctly.)